# Error: borrow of moved value because of unwrap

Tags: recursion, rust

I am solving the task https://leetcode.com/problems/same-tree/description/
-- Given the roots of two binary trees p and q, write a function to check if they are the same or not.

My code

```
// Definition for a binary tree node.
// #[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
// pub struct TreeNode {
//   pub val: i32,
//   pub left: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
//   pub right: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
// }
// 
// impl TreeNode {
//   #[inline]
//   pub fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
//     TreeNode {
//       val,
//       left: None,
//       right: None
//     }
//   }
// }
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;
impl Solution {
    pub fn is_same_tree(p: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>, q: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>) -> bool {
        if p.is_none() && q.is_none() {
            return true;
        }
        let mut pp = p.unwrap();
        let mut qq = q.unwrap();
        if (p.is_none() || q.is_none()) || pp.borrow().val != qq.borrow().val {
            return false;
        }
        return Self::is_same_tree(pp.borrow().left.clone(), qq.borrow().left.clone()) &&
               Self::is_same_tree(pp.borrow().right.clone(), qq.borrow().right.clone());
             
    }
}
```

I have an error

> borrow of moved value: `p`

Is it possible to fix my recursive solution without usage of `match` keyword.
I mean that I don't want to use match -- solution like this (the solution is working fine)

```
impl Solution {
    pub fn is_same_tree(p: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>, q: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>) -> bool {
        match(p, q) {
            (None, None) => true,
            (Some(p), Some(q)) => {
                let pp = p.borrow();
                let qq = q.borrow();
                return pp.val == qq.val &&
                       Self::is_same_tree(pp.left.clone(), qq.left.clone()) &&
                       Self::is_same_tree(pp.right.clone(), qq.right.clone());
            },
            _ => false
        }
             
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `p.is_none() || q.is_none()` they can't be none at that point since `unwrap()` panics if they were. But your alternative is by far more idiomatic Rust.

Comment: Alternatively replace the body of the function by `p == q` sometimes leetcode is just too funny in what's asked.